# Tibco Businessworks Date Format

Tags: date, datetime, xpath, tibco, businessworks

I'm trying to format a date in Tibco Businessworks 6.2.2 in the following format:

```
06-AUG-2015 12:11 AM
```

I've found the picture string on several websites for xpath that, according to those who use them, will format the date like this. I've not been able to figure out how to only get the AUG instead of AUGUST without JUNE and JULY showing up as JUN and JUL.

Here is the xpath I'm using:

```
format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), '[D01]-[MNn, *-3]-[Y0001] [h01]:[m01] [PN]')
```

Here is the output I'm getting:

```
06-August-2015 12:11 AM
```

Any and all information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), '[D01]-[MN, *-3]-[Y0001] [h01]:[m01] [PN]')
```

Output :

> 15-DEC-2015 05:56 P.M.

ref : http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#date-time-examples

Answer (score 1):

In Tibco BW you can use substring on the final output - for the month'AUGUST' with index from 0 to 3. But this  seems to be a work around.

A better approach is to  write a common process of Date formtter with JavaCode activity from Java Palette. It doesn't and need any specific jar/lib import.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm a").format(new Date())
```

Comment: That's what I have going on now as a workaround, but I'm trying to avoid using java code. This will be handed off to a group of people who know nothing about code to maintain, so the less "hackey" I get the better.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried MMM in stead of MNn?

Comment: MMM outputs 14-8-2015 10:21 AM

Answer (score 0):

I used this function. (BW 5.12)

```
tib:format-dateTime('dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a', current-dateTime())
```

Out

06-Jul-2017 11:34 AM